# Using assoc-in to permanently change a value in a map Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure

sorry about the huge amount of questions.

I have a map of cards:

```
    (def cards
  {
    :card1 {:name "Wisp"              :type "Monster"     :damage 1   :health 1   :cost 0   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card2 {:name "Spider Tank"       :type "Monster"     :damage 3   :health 4   :cost 3   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card3 {:name "Boulder Fist Ogre" :type "Monster"     :damage 6   :health 7   :cost 6   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card4 {:name "Bloodfen Raptor"   :type "Monster"     :damage 3   :health 2   :cost 2   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card5 {:name "Chillwind Yeti"    :type "Monster"     :damage 4   :health 5   :cost 4   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card6 {:name "Magma Rager"       :type "Monster"     :damage 5   :health 1   :cost 3   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card7 {:name "War Golem"         :type "Monster"     :damage 7   :health 7   :cost 7   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card8 {:name "Oasis Snapjaw"     :type "Monster"     :damage 2   :health 7   :cost 4   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card9 {:name "River Crocolisk"   :type "Monster"     :damage 2   :health 3   :cost 2   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card10 {:name "Murloc Raider"    :type "Monster"     :damage 2   :health 1   :cost 1   :ability 0 :active true}
    :card11 {:name "Northshire Cleric":type "Monster"     :damage 1   :health 3   :cost 1   :ability 2 :active true}
    :card12 {:name "Nat Peagle"       :type "Monster"     :damage 0   :health 4   :cost 2   :ability 4 :active true}
    :card13 {:name "Molten Giant"     :type "Monster"     :damage 8   :health 8   :cost 20  :ability 0 :active true}
    }
 )
```

These cards are in a list that makes up my board:

```
(def board1 (list (:card3 cards) (:card4 cards) (:card11 cards) nil nil nil nil))
```

What I want to do is change the active flag on a card to false from true.

I know that I can do this to my cards collection directly by:

```
user=> (assoc-in (:card11 cards) [:active] false)
{:ability 2, :name "Northshire Cleric", :type "Monster", :damage 1, :active false, :health 3, :cost 1}
```

I'm trying to build a function which, when given a collection (the board) and a number (nth) card. Makes this card in this board be false permanently.

I've been trying with atoms but had no joy so far.

```
(test-function board1 1)

(defn test-function [coll number]
  (let [test (atom coll)]
    (swap! test assoc-in (get (nth @test number)) [:active] false)
    (println test)))
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and whether there is a cleaner way to do this without using atoms.

Comment: What do you mean by "permanently" here?  Also, you should use boolean `true` and `false` rather than the `f` and `t` strings.

Comment: I'll change to true and false. From my understanding when I change the "true" to "false" it doesn't stay false.  I'd like it to remain true or false for the duration of the function if possible.

Comment: @JT93 What do you mean by "change"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JT93

As per your comment, you want to do away with the `atom` and have a clean update approach.

If you can clarify what you mean by permanently with more information in your question. For example: Do you want to maintain the board state of cards throughout the lifetime of the execution? If so, you may need to use an `atom` although Clojure has a few different approaches in addition.

First, consider changing the definition of `board1` to a vector and not a list. You can then do away with arcane logic and just use `assoc-in` with very little fanfare:

```
(def board1 [(:card3 cards) (:card4 cards) (:card11 cards) nil nil nil nil])

(defn test-function [coll number]
    (assoc-in coll [number :active] false))

(clojure.pprint/pprint (test-function board1 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your atom outside your `let` block.  The way you have it, you are re-binding it each time.  The `atom` is a good choice for stateful things, so declare your atom like so:

```
(def cards (atom
  {:card1 {:name "Wisp" :active true}
   :card2 {:name "Spider Tank" :active true}}))
```

Then you can write your function to swap in `false` like so:

```
(defn myfunc [coll number]
  (swap! coll assoc-in [(str :card number) :active] false ))
```

You don't want two different functions, one for setting to `true` and one for setting to `false`though.  You should take this the next step and make it read the current boolean value, then `assoc-in` the opposite value.  (Also notice, I kept the sample data sample very small). ;)

Comment: `update-in` with `not` seems a better way to do that last one.

Comment: Cards are in a list and the number is the index into the list, as per the original question. Creating a string as you've shown will work directly on the map but not the list.